# Function seems to always return true

Tags: javascript

I have a function that should return a `Boolean` based on whether or not a token exists in the local storage, assigning it to a variable.

```
export var isLoggedInVar = () => {
 return localStorage.getItem("token") ? true : false;
};
```

My code works if I explicitly set `isLoggedInVar` to either `true` or `false`, and it also works when there's a token in the local storage (console logs `true`). However, when there's no value in the local storage, the code renders the `true` option by default, and the value in console log is `f()` instead of `false`. Sounds pretty simple, but I can't understand what am I missing here?

Comment: The first operand of the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), is the condition. If you put `true` there, it will always execute and return the second operand.

Comment: Thank you, I edited. The same behavior still exists. Had it right in the code, but typed here wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In the below ternary conditional statement, we check if `localStorage.getItem("token")` exists first, if yes then we will return `true` else `false`.

In your code, the ternary condition was always set to true so the second part, ie false was never being returned.

```
export var isLoggedInVar = () => {
  return localStorage.getItem("token") ? true : false;
};
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Damn, my bad... late night coding. But still, the same behavior. I will update the question, thank you! The var is used in isLoggedIn function, and it console logs isLoggedIn: ƒ and renders the true option.

Comment: hi, It's working fine.
I have updated the answer with the resulting snapshot